# Is an infinity limit comparison test inconclusive?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

Is a limit comparison test for let's say:

$$a_n= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\tan{\frac{1}{n\sqrt{n}}},$$
we choose $$b_n = \frac{1}{n^{3/2}}.$$

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} = \infty. $$

Inconclusive, or does this state that both series are convergent, since $0< \infty$.

Comment: Are you sure that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}=\infty$? What is $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan x}{x}$?

Comment: @StinkingBishop I think so because it is equal to $\tan{\frac{1}{n\sqrt{n}}}*n^{3/2}$

Comment: The tangent tends to zero the other factor tends to $\infty$. This does not mean that the limit is $\infty$. Note that $\tan x \sim x$ as $x\to 0$.

Comment: @Gary I see, so it is 0 then and the series diverge ?

Comment: @BiliDebili It is actually $1$. Try to prove it.

Comment: $$
\frac{{a_n }}{{b_n }} = n^{3/2} \tan \left( {\frac{1}{{n^{3/2} }}} \right) = \frac{1}{\cos \left( {\frac{1}{{n^{3/2} }}} \right)}\frac{{\sin \left( {\frac{1}{{n^{3/2} }}} \right)}}{{\frac{1}{{n^{3/2} }}}}.
$$ Does this ring a bell?